# Shader that can detect intersection

Tags: unity, shaders

I am a beginner shader worlds, it is much difficult to learn(anyhow i try sometime).I am searching a shader that can sense collision/intersection with other objects so that i can stop its rendering at that intersection point. I currently get this shader it allow to detect the intersection(don't know how) but its mesh rendering doesn't stop.

```
Shader "Custom/IntersectionHighlights"
{
    Properties
    {
        _RegularColor("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, .5) //Color when not intersecting
        _HighlightColor("Highlight Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, .5) //Color when intersecting
        _HighlightThresholdMax("Highlight Threshold Max", Float) = 1 //Max difference for intersections
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent"  }
        Pass
        {
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
            ZWrite Off
            Cull Off

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma target 3.0
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            uniform sampler2D _CameraDepthTexture; //Depth Texture
            uniform float4 _RegularColor;
            uniform float4 _HighlightColor;
            uniform float _HighlightThresholdMax;

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 projPos : TEXCOORD1; //Screen position of pos
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
                o.projPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos);

                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) : COLOR
            {
                float4 finalColor = _RegularColor;

                //Get the distance to the camera from the depth buffer for this point
                float sceneZ = LinearEyeDepth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture,
                                                         UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.projPos)).r);

                //Actual distance to the camera
                float partZ = i.projPos.z;

                //If the two are similar, then there is an object intersecting with our object
                float diff = (abs(sceneZ - partZ)) /
                    _HighlightThresholdMax;

                if(diff <= 1)
                {
                    finalColor = lerp(_HighlightColor,
                                      _RegularColor,
                                      float4(diff, diff, diff, diff));
                }

                half4 c;
                c.r = finalColor.r;
                c.g = finalColor.g;
                c.b = finalColor.b;
                c.a = finalColor.a;

                return c;
            }

            ENDCG
        }
    }
    FallBack "VertexLit"
}
```

Current effect of this shader is
[image]

The marked area by arrow should not need to be render

Comment: An image comparing your intended effect with your current results would help clarify this question. By "stop its rendering at that intersection point" do you mean depth testing? It sounds like the depth ordering we do with a depth buffer (ie. each fragment checks the depth buffer at the location it will be drawn, and if there's already a surface rendered nearer to the camera, it aborts its rendering rather than drawing "through" the other object). [Transparent shaders need a little extra care to approximate correct depth ordering](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/72632/39518)

Comment: Actually you got it right. I am not familiar with the terms of shaders and graphics. I just want to stop the rendering at specific point where it intersect with other object.

Comment: @DMGregory I have also update the question with picture. please check

Comment: Ahh, you're asking for something completely different. You won't get this from a shader alone, as you effectively need a raycast from each drawn point back to its source to check if any occluders lie in-between. You could approximate this by rendering a depth map from the source point of view, effectively a shadow map. Or, if your geometry is simple, do your raycasts CPU-side and deform your mesh to conform to what it hits. Try telling us a bit more about the context in which you're using this effect - there may be some options better-suited to your case than others.

Comment: but you told me that "each fragment checks the depth buffer at the location it will be drawn, and if there's already a surface rendered nearer to the camera, it aborts its rendering rather than drawing "through" the other object". I guess it is possible?

Comment: Maybe this will help you undertand the main question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118862/map-the-custom-triangle-to-camera-s-view-angle

Comment: The effect I described is what stops the yellow-outlined frustum box from drawing in that middle section, where the brown ground plane is closer to the viewer (see how it gets cut off at the point of contact?). But down where you've indicated with the red arrow, the brown plane has *not* been drawn on those pixels, so it has not left any information in the depth buffer there, hence the need for other solutions. Stepping back, it sounds like what you want to do is "Visualize a camera frustum, stopping where it meets an obstacle" - is that an accurate summary?

Comment: Thanks for your so much technical insight which i able to get half. so what can be the solution